# How can I count entities by their label for precision and recall

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, pos-tagger

I have some data which are like this:

```
           True         Predicted

A          M            M
Pizza      B-Food       B-Food
with       I-Food       I-Food
Peppers    I-Food       I-Food   [correct prediction]
And        M            En
Cuba       B-Drink      B-Drink  
Libre      I-Drink      B-Drink  [wrong prediction]
```

I want to count those entities in order to find True Positive, False Positive and False Negative for precision and recall calculation. I'm very confused on how can I compare those tags since an entity must be composed of a sequence of tags. In this example an entity is Pizza with Peppers which is tagged as B-Food, I-Food, I-Food so as u can see this match with the prediction and It can be considered a True Positive for the -Food tag.

I read that precision is TP / (TP + FP) and recall is TP / (TP + FN) but I can't understand how to store those values for the tags in order to computer precision and recall. I can't use any libraries, I have to compare, count and compute.

```
def precision_recall(true_tags, predicted_tags):

    # storing all the true and predicted tags for comparing
    t_tags = [pair[1] for pair in true_tags]
    p_tags = [pair[1] for pair in predicted_tags]

    #compare here
```

In the end I want a thing like this:

```
        Precision    Recall
Food      0.810      0.123
Loc       0.340      0.723
Drink     0.114      0.654
```

Comment: It's really not clear what your problem is. Are you trying to say that adjacent lines should be grouped into one entry and all the tags in that entry should match the prediction? How would you handle the case when two adjacent lines do not belong to the same entry?

Comment: Precision and recall for a multinomial classifier will require a slightly different formula; TP/FP/TN/FN only really makes sense for a binomial classifier (where "positive" is the verdict that a sample belongs in the category, and "negative" is the verdict that it doesn't).

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-metrics-made-simple-part-i-precision-and-recall-9250280bddc2 is a nice approachable exposition

Comment: @tripleee read them as column. Pizza with Peppers true tags are [B-Food, I-Food, I-Food]. The prediction for Pizza with Peppers is [B-Food, I-Food, I-Food].
the tags match --> true positive for Food += 1

My problem is that I don't know how to update my counter only when I have a FULL match (in this case [B-Food, I-Food, I-Food]). If the prediction was [B-Food, I-Food, B-Food] I should consider it as false negative because I have not a full match.

But I'm now on NLP + python so I may have misunderstood these concepts.

Comment: @tripleee I wanted to do something like this: https://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/05/09/Named_Entity_Evaluation/

Comment: If you know how to parse the input into a set of labels reliably then the rest should be trivial. `if expected_list == predicted_list:` you have the right category, otherwise chalk it up as a false. It's not clear what `pair` is in your code, though.

Comment: Your comment doesn't really clarify anything; once you have figured out how to articulate this better, please [edit] your question instead of posting additional comments.